# Smart select is always initialized in framework7

Tags: html-framework-7

There are no option to make allow a smart select to be uninitialized (i.e. no item selected by default).
even if the tag selected in not exist. (the first item will be selected by default)

Answer (score 2):

I workaround it by adding a dummy select element with attr "selected" and "disabled" and adding a css class to add `display:none` to the `smart-select-page li.disabled`

full code

html

```
<li>
<a href="#" class="item-link smart-select" data-searchbar="true" data-back-on-select="true" data-searchbar-placeholder="{{title}}">
    <select name="{{elementId}}">
        <option value="" selected disabled></option>
        {{#each items_arr}}<option value="{{@index}}">{{this}}</option>{{/each}}
    </select>
    <div class="item-content">
        <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item-title">{{title}}</div>
            <div class="item-after"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
</li>
```

css

```
smart-select-page li.disabled{
    display:none
}
```

[image: screen shot 2016-02-02 at 5 23 38 pm]